# What to do if I can not conclude the corollary of a theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, soft-question, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

I know that my question seems subjective but also it is possible that there may be a *general rule* which I do not know currently. 
 While I am studying abstract algebra, sometimes I can not conclude the corollary of the theorems that are stated. I revise what I do in the related chapter, then think about the theorem, try to make claims about what can be said after the theorem. First, I do the work I mentioned above. Second, I try to prove  the corollary. If I have enough time, I spend days to give a proof.

An example:

I was studying the PID's from Dummit & Foote's Algebra -which I have studied multiple of times before- $3$ days ago and saw the following theorem and its corollary:

> **Theorem.**
>   Every nonzero prime ideal in a PID is a maximal ideal.
>
> **Corollary**. If $R$ is any commutative ring such that the polynomial ring $R[x]$ is a PID, then $R$ is necessarily a field.

I did not look at the proof and still working on it.(Using *"tools"* like an ideal  $I$ is maximal then $R/I$ is a field etc.)

I go back, study again. Think, think, think. Use different proof methods.

What is the thing that I am not aware of? What can be done in my situtation?

Comment: Well $(x)$ seems to be a prime ideal of $R[x]$, and $R[x]/(x) \simeq R$

Comment: @Max Okay, so how did you think of that proof?

Comment: I'm not sure it is clear what you are asking. It seems that you want to know in general how to prove things. You specifically highlight corollaries, but I don't think this changes much. As is, this question, in my opinion, is to broad. Flagged for this reason.

Comment: Well exactly how the OP explained : thinking about tools such as $R/I$, etc.

Comment: @SeanEnglish, I am not asking how to prove things. The book says there is some fact, and in conclusion, that(the corollary) happens. However, the result does not seem so natural to me; the corollary is not the first thing that comes to my mind after I see the theorem. Why it does not seem so natural to me is the question I am asking, what do I miss, what is the thing that I can not see.

Comment: @Ninja Sure, but in essence, that is the same as asking how you prove things(except maybe... it is more like "how do you prove things after you are told the main tool necessary?") Finding the proof for a corollary is the same process as finding a general proof, except you have a hint of something that may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general method for finding the "obvious" proofs, other than general experience. However, I can tell you what in this specific situation hints toward the solution outlined in the comments to the question above. There are a lot of interconnecting facts that together point toward this solution.

An ideal is maximal iff you get a field when you divide out by it. Thus the theorem says something about what quotient rings you can get (i.e. if you get an integral domain, and it is not the ring itself, then it must be a field). Also, because $R[x]$ is an integral domain, $(x)$ is prime, and $R\simeq R[x]/(x)$ (this quotient is the main way of getting information about $R$ if you know a lot about $R[x]$ in the first place; we know more about quotients than about subrings). All these facts come together with the theorem itself, and the corollary is the result.